# No modal is shown in Angular when I come from a navigation

Tags: angular, typescript, bootstrap-modal

While in a view, I do a navigation like this:

`this.router.navigateByUrl('/view1?result=' + action);`

In view 1, I get the value of the result parameter in the function ngOnInit:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.activatedRoute.queryParamMap.subscribe(queryParams => {
    if (queryParams.get('result') != null) {
      this.resultIdentity = queryParams.get('result');
    }
  });
}
```

Then, depending on the value of "result" I execute a click event to a button sentenced by ViewChild.

```
@ViewChild('alertButton') alertButton;

ngAfterViewInit(): void {
  if (this.resultIdentity === 'XXX') {
      this.alertButton.nativeElement.click();
  }
}
```

If I go directly to the URL I see the alert (even if I do F5). But if I load the view using the router.navigateByUrl I don't see the modal, it stays with the black semi-transparent background, but the modal doesn't appear.

Any idea why this might be happening to me when I do a navigation and not when I do an F5?

Thanks

Comment: Adding setTimeout in click button event, it works correctly.

Answer (score 0):

A working example would be great to answer your question in detail.

But I guess that the problem lies within the async nature of `ngOnInit`, `ngAfterviewInit` and `...queryParamsMap.subscribe()`.

You can not expect that these functions will be executed in the same order all the time.

I would suggest to place console.log's in each function to see if the order differs between your two use cases.